# Dynamic titles and meta tags using GulpJs

Tags: gulp

I'm using GulpJS and `gulp-token-replace` to replace variables within an HTML file, such as title and meta tags. It's working great, but I'm stuck with only one configuration file (`config-title-meta.json`). I want to have an individual configuration file for each folder, so that I might be able to edit "main" variables for all html pages, but customize others, without having to edit each individual page. Am I using the correct tool for this?

`gulpfile.js`:

```
var replace = require('gulp-token-replace');

gulp.task('compile-html', function() {
  var config = require('./config-title-meta.json');
  return gulp.src([
    './**/*.html',
    '!header.html', // ignore
    '!footer.html' // ignore
    ])
    .pipe(fileinclude({
      prefix: '@@',
      basepath: '@file'
    }))
    .pipe(replace({global:config}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(Paths.scripts.dest));
});
```